# Method is not called, but no error appears

Tags: java

I'm writing my first simple StarCraft Broodwar AI and I have a problem with my 2 custom classes. The idea is to have an array of reservations that stores temporary reservations of minerals and vespene gas, so I can create a reservation when ordering a worker to build a structure so the other workers and buildings don't spend the resources in the meantime until the worker arrives at the building site. The problem is, when the standard BWAPI event listener "onFrame" launches the `countDownReservations()` method, the individual array rows are not called at all and the rest of the AI isn't processed at all and is effectively broken.

So when I start the bot, nothing happens except for the console printing out "bingo" and
"0 started"
over and over again for every frame.
The line "bingo1" doesn't even appear once, so somehow the program crashes when calling this method "countDown()". Sadly it doesn't give an error at all and there are no pre-compiler warnings whatsoever.

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Console output:

[image: console output]

Java project:

[image: java project]

Starcraft bot:

```
@Override
public void onFrame() {
    System.out.println("bingo");
    resourceReservations.countDownReservations();

public class ResourceReservations {

    private ResourceReservation[] resourceReservationArray = new ResourceReservation[15];

    public ResourceReservations() {

    }

    // looks through the array for a reservation with 0 time left on it (which should thus be empty)
    // - and overwrites the empty reservation with a new one
    // if no empty reservation can be found, nothing happens and a warning is output to the console
    public void addReservation(int minerals, int gas, int timer) {
        for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < 15; loopCounter++) {
            if (resourceReservationArray[loopCounter].getReservationTime() == 0) {
                resourceReservationArray[loopCounter].setMinerals(minerals);
                resourceReservationArray[loopCounter].setGas(gas);
                resourceReservationArray[loopCounter].setTimerInSeconds(timer);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Failed to add a reservation, no free space in array!");
    }

    // sums up all reserved minerals in the array
    public int reservedMinerals() {
        int reservedMinerals = 0;
        for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < 15; loopCounter++) {
            reservedMinerals = reservedMinerals + resourceReservationArray[loopCounter].getMinerals();
        }
        return reservedMinerals;
    }

    // sums up all reserved vespene gas in the array
    public int reservedVespeneGas() {
        int reservedVespeneGas = 0;
        for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < 15; loopCounter++) {
            reservedVespeneGas = reservedVespeneGas + resourceReservationArray[loopCounter].getGas();
        }
        return reservedVespeneGas;
    }

    // count down all the reservations
    public void countDownReservations() {
        for (int loopNumber = 0; loopNumber < 15; loopNumber++) {
            System.out.println(loopNumber + " started");
            resourceReservationArray[loopNumber].countDown();
            System.out.println(loopNumber + " completed");
        }
    }
}

public class ResourceReservation {

    private int minerals = 0;

    private int vespeneGas = 0;

    private int reservationTime = 0;

    public ResourceReservation() {

    }

    // read status - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    public int getGas() {
        return vespeneGas;
    }
    public int getMinerals() {
        return minerals;
    }
    public int getReservationTime() {
        return reservationTime;
    }

    // update status - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    public void setGas(int newGas) {
        vespeneGas      = newGas;
    }
    public void setMinerals(int newMinerals) {
        minerals        = newMinerals;
    }
    public void setTimerInFrames(int newTimer) {
        reservationTime = newTimer;
    }
    public void setTimerInSeconds(int newTimer) {
        reservationTime = newTimer * 60;
    }

    // clear  - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    public void initialize() {
        minerals        = 0;
        vespeneGas      = 0;
        reservationTime = 0;
    }

    // count down - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    public void countDown() {
        System.out.println("bingo1");
        if (reservationTime > 0) {
            System.out.println("bingo2");
            reservationTime = reservationTime - 1;
            System.out.println("bingo3");
            if (reservationTime == 0) {
                System.out.println("bingo4");
                initialize();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear where you called `addReservation`... So, we can't know when `if (reservationTime > 0) {` is ever true. Please make sure you have a [mcve] and use a debugger on your code

Comment: I just debugged it and saw that every row in the 15-row-array = 'null' So he's trying to check if the timer of reservation #0 is to be reduced and he doesn't find a reservation in the array at all. How can I initialize it properly so the 15 reservations are in the array?

Comment: So if your objects were null, your code should have had an error, but you did not see one?

Comment: I only saw the error when debugging. Java said "null pointer exception" then. But without debugging, nothing happened and java skipped the rest of the code every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just solved it, the problem was that the 15 Reservations didn't exist

Adding this loop to the head of the Reservations class solved the problem:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        resourceReservationArray[x] = new ResourceReservation();
    }
```

public class ResourceReservations {

```
private ResourceReservation[] resourceReservationArray = new ResourceReservation[15];

public ResourceReservations() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        resourceReservationArray[x] = new ResourceReservation();
    }
}
```

Thanks for putting up with me and reminding me of debugging. Hadn't done that in java yet. ^^

Edit: Oh and by the way, I reduced the number of reservations to 5 and haven't seen it overflow yet in about 20 games.